# Can't get the following meta to redirect but can only work with header redirect

Tags: php

I am trying to use one of the redirect options but for some reason, I can't get the meta redirect to work. I can only get the header redirect to work.

header("Location: ../student_registration.php?id=$userid");

```
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../student_registration.php?id=$userid')";
```

Comment: It still doesn't redirect... this is weird though.... unless my syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://example.com/student_registration.php?id=.$userid.'";
```

**OR**

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://example.com/student_registration.php?id=$userid'";
```

Comment: That doesn't work as well.. It seems to be working on my other pages but not for this one... I just have to use header..

Comment: but this is strange as it does work on my other pages

Comment: for some reason, it does work now but I think it is better to have header right

Comment: if it working, so accept it as the answer or let me know if any issue.

Comment: What are the periods for? `id=.$userid.'`?